# map() only on first level of children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `map()` function to select the children elements of my dropzone:

```
$('#DropZone div').map(function(i, item){
})
```

The dropzone's structure is like this:

```
<div id="DropZone">
    <div id="firstImage">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="SecondImage">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The map function then returns every div inside the DropZone, but I'd like to retrieve only the `#firstImage` div and the `#secondImage` div. My question is: how can I use the `map()` function to only retrieve the first layer of children and not the whole structure?

Comment: What do you want to do after `map()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the direct descendant selector:

```
$('#DropZone > div').map(function(i, item){
    // your logic here...
})
```